# How to unnest tags in beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a html document that looks similar to this:

```
<div>
<h2>Title</h2>
<div>
 <div>
  <div>
   <img alt="Some image" src="blah.gif"/>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to extract it to look ultimately like this (ie remove empty nested divs)

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<div>
  <img alt="Some image" src="blah.gif"/>
</div>
```

I don't mind maintaining the outer div if it contains something, but anything which is nested unecessarily I would like to strip out.

To clarify, when I have a div, that is contains another div and that is all, then I want to remove (unwrap) the inner div, ie so instead of

div>div>div>div>div>img

I just want

div>img

Comment: "remove empty nested divs" doesn't really describe what you want to achieve... there are no empty divs in your example.

Answer (score 0):

here is POC that I wrote, any suggestion to the code is welcome.

You can add criteria to the function `test` and it will recursively find the element matching criteria and remove the most outside layer.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mytext ="""
<div>
<h2>
 At least he didn't go in for the hug.
</h2>
<div>
 <div>
  <div>
   <img alt="At least he didn't go in for the hug." src="handshake-fails-are-embarrassing\9lmzspj.gif"/>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(mytext)


def test(x):
    children = x.find_all(recursive=False)
    try:
        # only one child
        cri_1 = (len(children) == 1)
        # same name as its child
        cri_2 = (children[0].name == x.name)
        # no attribute but tag name
        cri_3 = (len(x.attrs) == 0)
        return cri_1 and cri_2 and cri_3
    except:
        return False

while soup.find_all(lambda x: test(x)):
    elements = soup.find_all(lambda x: test(x))
    elements[0].unwrap()

print soup.prettify()
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div>
   <h2>
    At least he didn't go in for the hug.
   </h2>
   <div>
    <img alt="At least he didn't go in for the hug." src="handshake-fails-are-embarrassing\9lmzspj.gif"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```